# How to pass a value from Laravel blade to a vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I am working on laravel / vue project and i want to pass a value from laravel blade to the vue component but i get this error :

> Missing required prop: "id" at

The vue component:

```
export default {
    props:{
        id:{
            required : true
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.id)
    },
}
```

The Laravel blade:

```
<div id="add_product">
   <add-product :id="{{$product_id}}"></add-product>
</div>
```

Comment: make sure $product_id is not empty

Comment: i did echo it, it is not empty.

Answer (score -1):

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

you should add props true to router

```
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true },
```

Edit :
Just remove : from :id
 `<add-product id="{{$product_id}}"></add-product>`

Comment: i am not using vue route.